# Ubuntu 16.04 Sublime Text 3 Command Palette and Enter key Completion not working

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext, ubuntu-16.04

I already reinstall sublime text 3 many times but it wont fix my command palette. When i press `Ctrl + Shift + P` it open the Command Palette but if i try to type something the Palette will close. I want it to be the same with my other laptop, that if i `Ctrl + Shift + P` and type something then some hints will show and if i press enter it will trigger auto complete.

Answer (score 0):

I already solve the problem just turning the numlock off. here's the answer source [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1059042/sublime-3-command-palette-is-being-closed-on-any-key-pressed)